# NGINX page redirect to homepage

Tags: web, nginx, webserver

I have found answers here on redirecting php and error codes, but not from one page to another. An aspect of my website is a FTP uploader and my extension is mywebsite/ss/xyz.file. Currently, I have an index.html setup in /ss so people may not see my screenshots, however I would rather just give them a 404, without making all 404s go to /ss, or automatically redirect them to my homepage.

My current serverblock config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/xxx.xxx/html;
        index index.html phpinfo.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mangoman.me www.xxx.xxx

        location \ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out my own answer.

```html
        location /ss {
        return 404;
        }
```